# Oracle multiple statments do not run correctly

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a file with 3 "create type" statements. I do not understand why, when I run the script it creates only the first type. When I open created type I see all three create statements inside. What am I missing here?

**CODE:**

```
create type SplitPathTableType as table of varchar2(450);

create TYPE TSMNodesRecord AS OBJECT (
NodeID number(20),
IsDataNode number(1),
Path nvarchar2 (450),
ParentID number(20),
TimeStep number(20)
);

create type TSMNODESTABLE as table of TSMNODESRECORD;
```

Comment: Please post up the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need / after each statement...

```
create type SplitPathTableType as table of varchar2(450);
/

create TYPE TSMNodesRecord AS OBJECT (
NodeID number(20),
IsDataNode number(1),
Path nvarchar2 (450),
vParentID number(20),
TimeStep number(20)
);
/

create type TSMNODESTABLE as table of TSMNODESRECORD;
/
```

Comment: It works, but you need to as it is in the example use slash in a new line.